# Missing wi-fi firmwares after Debian installation

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, debian

I installed my debian few days ago, and I had error messages saying that firmwares were missing. I managed to solve this problem by adding manually them into the `/firmware` folder of my bootable usb key.
The Wi-Fi seems to be working well on my laptop, but the `dmesg -l err` command gives me these errors :

```
[    2.159719] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: failed to load i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (-2)
[    2.159721] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
[    5.309587] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin (-2)
[    5.309708] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin (-2)
[    5.310166] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin (-2)
```

It's the same errors I had when I installed debian.
Can someone explain me how to solve them ? I already installed the `firmware-atheros` package but nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

You may use `apt-file` to search for missing (firmware) files in uninstalled packages.

```
$ apt-file search i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
firmware-misc-nonfree: /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin
```

So in your case you may try to install `firmware-misc-nonfree` package.

---

Alternatively you may use https://packages.debian.org/search

[For bullseye (current stable) version it produces](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=buster&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=i915%2Fkbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin):

```
File                                    Packages
/lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin  firmware-misc-nonfree
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem for i915 ! But the problem still remains for ath10k...

Comment: You may try package `firmware-atheros`. https://packages.debian.org/en/buster/firmware-atheros] : `This package contains the binary firmware for … ath10k … drivers.`

Comment: As said in my post, i already installed the firmware-atheros package...